# Javascript evaluating HTML special characters, breaks function call in AJAX result

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

I've been working on a custom form completion for a site/tool I've been building.

I got the search to work, it displays the results in a little div below the input field. I want to allow a user to see the results, click on the appropriate result, and allow it to populate the form fields with the corresponding data. This works when the data has no special characters in it (IE an apostrophe), but if it has an apostrophe, the function call breaks. I know well enough to have the special characters changed into HTML special characters:

```
&#39;
```

And, I have done that when adding the data to the database. The problem is, since the function call is placed via AJAX into a div, the HTML special character is "evaluated" when placed into the page, and becomes the literal character. Here is an example of the function call:

```
onclick="popForm('1234', 'Some Name', 'Another Name', 'Someguy's Thing', '5678')"
```

Here's a list of all that I'm trying to do:

1. User enters data into a field
2. A javascript function captures the input via onkeyup(), and processes it
3. The function uses AJAX to make a call to a PHP script
4. The PHP script performs the search, grabs the results, and echo's a table containing the results, as well as a function call for onclick to populate the fields.
5. Javascript handles the results from AJAX, and adds the results to a div's innerhtml.
6. User clicks on a result, onclick is triggered, makes function call with string arguments wrapped in single quotes
7. Function adds the strings to the appropriate fields via
   document.getElementById("fieldname").value=string;
8. User submits form

Currently, we get all the way up to step 6, which is where it breaks, due to the literal apostrophe in the function call.

Any ideas on how to remedy this?

Comment: [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) anyone?

Comment: this is why you shouldn't use inline DOM0 event handlers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would seriously consider re-writing your logic.

1. don't use inline DOM0 event handlers - they're error prone for exactly this sort of reason
2. Return data, not function calls - `eval` is bad, mkay?
3. Bind a proper event handler (ideally using `element.addEventListener`) to a first-class function created on the fly and attached to the appropriate element

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the changes to how the function is called, but I was never using eval, I was simply outputting HTML that had an element inside with the inline event handler, and then placing the HTML into a div. My problem is that I'm returning at most 10 results, and each would have 5 variables I would need to store. Should I separate these functions into 2 AJAX calls? 1 to return limited results, then another I bind to onclick to gather the rest of the data, and then populate the form?

Comment: @Wally without seeing your actual AJAX code it's hard to say.  BTW, inline event handlers cause an implicit call to `eval`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm really new to javascript, so I'm trying to do the best that I can. I'll play around with what you said, I think I'll just use the `addEventListener`, and then do a second AJAX call to retrieve the extra data. This will speed up the initial search anyway, since it wouldn't be necessary to grab extra fields for every result.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with `preg_replace` all single-quote in your php script (before step 5) by a special string like "escape_quote", then, in your `popForm` function, replace with `.replace` "escape_quote" by a single-quote.

Comment: At the point with PHP still involved, the characters are all encoded as their HTML counterparts `&#39;` It loses them when being placed onto the page.

Comment: So, after encode special characters as HTML, you can replace `&#39;` by a special string or try to replace by `\&#39;`. You can also use the http://php.net/manual/fr/function.addslashes.php function before encoding as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your data that is passed to javascript function that is having apostrophe.

```
onclick="popForm('1234', 'Some Name', 'Another Name', 'Someguy\'s Thing', '5678')"
```

Comment: The data has been encoded with HTML special characters, and at the point of sending it to Javascript, still does.